# Unclickable EditText on resume

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I currently have an EditText inside a fragmented Tab, When you first enter the view the EditText only works correctly if i use

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

on the view, but it does allow my to hide the keyboard and bring it back be re-clicking.

However if i was to leave this view or if the phone goes to sleep for a moment and comes back the edit text is no longer clickable, I've tried forcing it to be focused using onresume but once you hide the keyboard you cannot regain focus again.

I feel as if i'm missing something regarding EditText Functionality in Fragments but i've had 0 luck finding anything relating to this problem.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have a similar problem.. It was solved handling the view focus..maybe you can find out a good solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786334/why-is-is-a-tabhost-stealing-focus-from-a-textview-in-android

Comment: You are right it's a very similar problem to this. I've been going insane thinking i'm the only one with this kind of problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your onResume you can do this:

```
EditText someEditText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.someEditText);
someEditText.requestFocus(); 
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(someEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: I feel like you didn't read my post since i actually put that i use that exact code already when the activity starts and it's not working correctly.

Comment: unclear what you asking, If it is not working then show us your full code

Comment: Not sure that will clarify it any more. 

Simply put EditText doesn't work on its own. 
I added in the SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE to fix this. 
If the view goes into the background for any reason and resumes the EditText becomes totally unclickable. 
The problem is the unclickable EditText at this point.

Comment: The Code is on the OnCreate, I did add it to the OnResume to test and the result was the keyboard would show as soon as the view appeared on screen. If i was to then hide the keyboard and attempt to re-click on the EditText it be unclickable again which isn't really a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then hiding keyboard from code, hide it from manifest on that activity. It will solve your problem i guess.

For hiding from manifest use this code -

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.app.xyz.youractivityname"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```